# How to convert media item picked from MPmediaPicker

Tags: ios, swift, mpmediapickercontroller

I'm using `MPmediaPickerController` when selecting a song from library it is an asset url  like `"ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=2937524894027399282"`. How to convert this format into `NSData` when using `Alamofire`.

```
func mediaPicker(_ mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection) {
     if mediaItemCollection.items.count == 1 {
         let aMediaItem = mediaItemCollection.items[0] as MPMediaItem
         print(aMediaItem.assetURL!)
         let data = NSData(contentsOf: aMediaItem.assetURL! as URL)!
     }
}
```

Last line is giving `nil` value when converting it into `NSData`.

Comment: I guess you will have to copy it into document directory first using FileManager.

Comment: i have the same issue. Please update the answer if you find one